# Как сделать возможным ввод только русских букв и пробелов в input?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На [этом сайте](http://shinaservice27.ru/) используется плагин, который в поле телефона
позволяет вводить только цифры. Можно ли для поля имени
сделать ввод только русских букв и пробелов? Никаких плагинов, позволяющих это реализовать, найти не могу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input type='text' id='abbr'>
```

И javascript:

```
// document.getElementById('abbr').addEventListener('keypress', fn, false);
$('#abbr').on('keypress', function() {
    var that = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var res = /[^а-я ]/g.exec(that.value);
        console.log(res);
        that.value = that.value.replace(res, '');
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: paste и input забыли и, мне кажется, с курсором надо шаманить,чтобы не было скачков при вводе.

Comment: @eicto старый дедовский метод, зато работает)) Автор думаю сможет допилить.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5

```html
<style>
    input:invalid {
        border-color: red;
    }
</style>

<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё ]+"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот немного подправленный пример с поддержкой заглавных букв и украинских символов (но принцип тот же):

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#cyr').on('keypress', function() {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        var res = /[^а-яА-ЯїЇєЄіІёЁ ]/g.exec(that.value);
        that.value = that.value.replace(res, '');
      }, 0);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=cyr />
```